# How to prove that $\lim (n a_n) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Series converges implies $\lim{n a_n} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/series-converges-implies-limn-a-n-0)

How do I show that the following:

If $ a_1 \geq a_2\geq ... \geq a_n\geq...$ and $\sum a_n$ converges then $\lim (n a_n) = 0$?

Thanks.

Comment: Since $a_n\to 0$ (this is necessary for the convergence of series), the monotonicity implies $a_n\ge 0$. With this additional condition, this is precisely the same question as [Series converges implies $\lim{n a_n} = 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/series-converges-implies-limn-a-n-0).

Comment: thanks, that was the same question.