# Question about serie and sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Series converges implies $\lim{n a_n} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/series-converges-implies-limn-a-n-0)

Someone can help me?  If $(a_n)$ is a decreasing sequence and $\sum a_n$ converges. Then $\lim {(n.a_n)} = 0$.

I don't have idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

By the Cauchy condensation test

$$\sum 2^m a_{2^m} < \infty$$

thus

$$\lim_n 2^m a_{2^m} =0$$

Now, for each $n$ chose some $m$ so that $2^m \leq n < 2^{m+1}$ and use

$$a_{2^m} \geq a_n \geq a_{2^{m+1}}$$