# Find an example where $a_n\ge0$ and $\limsup na_n =\infty$ but $\sum^\infty_{k=0}a_n$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis

Find an example where $a_n\ge0$ and $\limsup na_n =\infty$
but $\sum^\infty_{k=0}a_n$ converges.

I have tried making the $a_n$ oscillate to $0$, but still can't see how to get  $\limsup na_n =\infty$ because it seems like this requires $a_n$ to tend toward $0$ slower than $n$ to $\infty$.

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1825555/42969

Comment: The $\varlimsup$ allows you to get fancy from time to time in order to reach the infinite limit, while the rest of the sequence is well behaved and has a finite sum.