# Telescopic series multiplied by n

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, telescopic-series

If I have a convergent monotonic series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}a_n = S < \infty$ then I now that the corresponding telescoping series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_n-a_{n+1})$ converges too.

How can I demonstrate that another series

\begin{equation}
  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(a_n-a_{n+1})
\end{equation}

converges and has the same limit as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$?

I tried with the method of differences but I end up with

\begin{align}
  \lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{N}n(a_n-a_{n+1})
  &= -\lim_{N\to \infty}Na_{N+1} + \lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{N}a_n\\
  &= S -\lim_{N\to \infty}Na_{N+1}
\end{align}

$\lim_{N\to \infty}Na_{N+1}$ is now an indeterminate form $\infty \times 0$ and I have to show that it is equal to $0$.

Comment: Sorry but you really think that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_n-a_{n+1})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(a_n-a_{n+1})$$ in general?

Comment: If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n < \infty$ yes I do, why? Wait, I made a mistake in my original post.

Comment: Try $a_0=1$ and $a_n=0$ for every $n\geqslant1$ then.

Comment: I corrected my mistake that was not what I meant.

Comment: More reasonable now... but still incorrect. :-(

Comment: By the way, you should test the statements you are trying to prove on sequences such as $a_n=1/n$ if $n$ is a power of $2$, $a_n=0$ otherwise.

Comment: There probably was a condition $a_n \geqslant a_{n+1}$ somewhere, but it got lost.

Comment: Why is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ different from $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n(a_{n} - a_{n+1})$ then?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes you're right the sequence is monotonic, what does this change?

Comment: For example, it guarantees that $na_n \to 0$.

Comment: If you could please tell me how, then it would solve my question...

Comment: @FrancescoCarzaniga `Yes you're right the sequence is monotonic` Please edit this into the question, since that's essential information which you left out, and which changes the answer.

Comment: You're right I've corrected my question.

Comment: See for example [Series converges implies lim n a_n =0](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/series-converges-implies-limn-a-n-0).

Comment: Yes I saw that question and the relative answer, I was actually looking for a solution that did not require using the Cauchy condensation since we have not seen it in class yet and I would rather avoid having to prove it all over. Seems however it is the only possibility in this case.

Comment: "monotonic series" is absurd in this context, the missing hypothesis is that the **sequence** $(a_n)$ is monotonous.

Comment: "I was actually looking for a solution that did not require using the Cauchy condensation" Lucky you, Cauchy condensation is not used in the solutions on the other page.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. Then,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(a_n - a_{n+1}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n} - \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \left(\frac{2n+1}{n+1}\right)$$