# $\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=0\Rightarrow\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a nonnegative decreasing sequence satisfying $\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=0$.
Then, is it true that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$?

I think the answer is yes from my intuition since $a_n$ decreases faster than $1/n$ as $n\to\infty$, i.e.
$$\exists \alpha>0\ s.t.\  a_n\sim O(1/n^{1+\alpha}),$$
and we know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^s$ converges if $s>1$.
Actually this is the converse of [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4603/421723).

How can I prove this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is not true. $a_n = \frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The statement is false.  For example, you can verify that 
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n \ln(n)}
$$
satisfies your criterion but fails to converge (which you can verify by the integral test).

More generally: if $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is any increasing function with $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$, we'll find that $a_n = f(n) - f(n-1)$ leads to a divergent series (no matter how slowly $f$ diverges).

Comment: As @user8128 indicated in the comments

Comment: Okay, wonderful.

Comment: Oh, very simple counterexample! Thank you both.