# Suppose $\sum |a_n|$ converges. Is it true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n|a_n|=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> **Question**: Suppose $\sum |a_n|<\infty$. Is it true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n|a_n|=0$?

---

Suppose not. Then for some $\epsilon>0$ and for every $N\in{\bf N}$, there exists $n\geq N$ such that
$$
|a_n|>\frac{\epsilon}{n}.
$$
This is far from enough to conclude that $\sum |a_n|=\infty$. I think there might be counterexamples to the statement. Other than this I don't see what could be useful here.

Note that the monotonicity assumption has been dropped from this classical problem:

[Series converges implies $\lim{n a_n} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4603/9464)

Comment: You're right, I was too quick.

Comment: Suppose we take $a_{2^n} = 1/2^n$ for positive integers $n$, and $a_k = 0$ for all other $k$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a counterexample, take the sequence $$a_n=\cases{\frac 1n & if $n$ is a square\\0& otherwise}$$