# a series of general term (un) is convergent but n*(un) doesn't go to zero as n goes to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series

i have been struggling to find an example of a positive convergent series of general term (un), such that n*(un) doest go to 0 as n goes to infinity, i was able to prove that if (un) is a decreasing subsequence, then n*(un) goes to zero when n goes to infinity, but i can't think of a sequence that isn't monotonous and checks the conditions above.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You can modify the example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2530921/suppose-sum-a-n-converges-is-it-true-that-lim-n-to-inftyna-n-0).

Comment: Do you really mean a **series** $\Sum_{i=1}^{\infty}u_n$ or a **sequence** $u_n$ ?