# Counterexample: If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=1$ and each $a_n\geq 0,$ then $\lim\limits_{n\to}na_n=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

I'm studying for an exam and I ran into these problems. I'm having a feeling that this is not true. Hence, I don't need to prove. I need to just provide a counterexample. However, the appropriate example is not just coming. Any help?

Prove or give a counterexample:

1. If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=1$ and each $a_n\geq 0,$ then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}na_n=0$
2. If $a_n\geq 0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}na_n=0$

Comment: How do these questions differ? They both seem to be the same question modulo a scale factor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $a_{n^2}=\dfrac{1}{n^2}$ and $a_n=0$ otherwise. Then $na_n$ does not tend to $0$, and the series is convergent.

The sum is $\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$, but note you can multiply each term by the same constant to make the limit any nonzero number you wish.

---

Note, however, that if $a_n$ is also nonincreasing, the situation is different: [Series converges implies $\lim{n a_n} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/series-converges-implies-limn-a-n-0)

Comment: @BillO'Haran $na_n$ is either 1 or 0

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut: Please, how do I apply it to the above questions? It's for which of the exactly?

Comment: @Mike It's a counterexample to both.

Answer (score 3):

Prescribe $(a_n)_n$ by: $a_{n}=n^{-1}$ if $n=2^k$ for some positive integer $k$ and  $a_n=0$ otherwise.