# Trying to Prove a generalization of Raabe's test

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to prove (or disprove) a statement by Feld:

https://math.feld.cvut.cz/mt/txte/2/txe3ea2d.htm

It's a generalization of Raabe's test and it says that for a sequence $a_n$, for all n, if $a_n>0$ and $c_n$ is absolutely convergent and

$a_{n+1}/a_n = 1-A/n+c_n$

Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges iff $A>1$

I rewrite:

$n(1-a_{n+1}/a_n)=A-n c_n$

and take the limit on both sides as $n \to \infty$ and its proven by Raabe's simple test, as long as $\lim_{n \to \infty} n c_n=0$.

But it has been shown ([Series converges implies $\lim{n a_n} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/series-converges-implies-limn-a-n-0)) that $\lim_{n \to \infty} n c_n$ is not zero unless $c_n$ is non-increasing, so I'm stuck. Did Feld forget to add that $c_n$ is non-increasing, or is he right as it stands?