# Given $a_{n}\ge a_{n+1}>0$, how to prove $a_{n}=o(\frac{1}{n})$ is necessary for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ to converge?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I am working on an exercise from Zorich's Mathematical Analysis. The problem reads:

If $a_{n}\ge a_{n+1}>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges then $a_{n}=o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ as $n\to\infty$;

I understand that $a_{n}=o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ means $a_{n}=\alpha(n)\cdot\frac{1}{n}$ where $\alpha(n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. So let $\alpha(n)=n\cdot a_{n}$, then $a_{n}=\frac{\alpha(n)}{n}$, but I cannot seem to fully reason out from convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ to $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha(n)=0$. My partial result reasoning is as following:

Since $a_{n}\ge a_{n+1}>0$, follow Cauchy's proposition that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges if and only if $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^{k}a_{2^{k}}$ converges. Therefore,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^{k}a_{2^{k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^{k}\frac{\alpha\left(2^{k}\right)}{2^{k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\alpha\left(2^{k}\right)$$
Since it converges, it is necessary that $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\alpha\left(2^{k}\right)=0$. But that is only a subsequence of $\alpha(n)$.

(added per [Greg Martin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/16078/greg-martin)'s suggestion - thanks) Further from $a_{n+1}\ge a_{n}$ we have
\begin{align*}
    &a_{n}\ge a_{n+1}>0 \Rightarrow\frac{\alpha(n)}{n}\ge\frac{\alpha(n+1)}{n+1}>0\\
    \Rightarrow&\frac{\alpha(n+1)}{\alpha(n)}\le\frac{n+1}{n}=1+\frac{1}{n}\\
    \Rightarrow&\frac{\alpha(n+2)}{\alpha(n)}=\frac{\alpha(n+2)}{\alpha(n+1)}\cdot\frac{\alpha(n+1)}{\alpha(n)}\le\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)<\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2}\\
    &\quad\vdots
\end{align*}
So if $n=2^{k}$, then $2^{k+1}=2\cdot 2^{k}=2n$, thus
\begin{align*}
 \Rightarrow&\frac{\alpha(2^{k}+1)}{\alpha(2^{k})}\le 1+\frac{1}{2^{k}}\\
 \Rightarrow&\frac{\alpha(2^{k}+2)}{\alpha(2^{k})}=\frac{\alpha(2^{k}+2)}{\alpha(2^{k}+1)}\cdot\frac{\alpha(2^{k}+1)}{\alpha(2^{k})}<\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{k}}\right)^{2}\\
 &\quad\vdots\\
 \Rightarrow&\frac{\alpha(2^{k+1}-1)}{\alpha(2^{k})}=\frac{\alpha(2^{k+1}-1)}{\alpha(2^{k+1}-2)}\cdot\frac{\alpha(2^{k+1}-2)}{\alpha(2^{k+1}-3)}\cdots\frac{\alpha(2^{k}-1)}{\alpha(2^{k})}<\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{k}}\right)^{2^{k}-1}
\end{align*}

But we know
$$\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{k}}\right)^{2^{k}-1}=e$$
Thus $\alpha(2^{k}+d)<e\cdot\alpha(2^{k})$ is bounded for $d<2^{k}$, so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha(n)\le\lim_{k\to\infty}e\cdot\alpha(2^{k})=e\cdot\lim_{k\to\infty}\alpha(2^{k})=e\cdot 0=0$$

Hope I got it right..

Comment: From the definition of $\alpha(n)$ in terms of $a_n$, and the decreasing property of $\{a_n\}$, can you work out an upper bound for $|\alpha(n)|$ for $2^{k-1}<n<2^k$ in terms of $\alpha(2^{k-1})$ or $\alpha(2^k)$? (By the way, I recommend changing the title, as it seems to ask a much different question than the one in the post.)

Comment: Thanks, I editted the question to include that...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Series converges implies $\lim{n a_n} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/series-converges-implies-limn-a-n-0)

Comment: (your approach is close to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/71732) there)