# Let $x_{n}$ be a monotonously decreasing sequence converging to $0$. prove $nx_{n}$ is also convergent to $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

Let $x_{n}$ be a monotonously decreasing sequence converging to $0$.
The series $\sum x_{n}$ is convergent. Prove that $nx_{n}$ is also convergent to $0$.

I‘m kinda stuck here. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $(a_n)\subset[0,\infty)$ is non-increasing and $\sum a_n&lt;\infty$, then $\lim{n a_n} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/if-a-n-subset0-infty-is-non-increasing-and-sum-a-n-infty-then-lim)

Answer (score 0):

Using Cauchy criterion, one has
\begin{align*}
\left|\sum_{k=n}^{2n}x_{k}\right|<\epsilon,
\end{align*}
but then
\begin{align*}
\left|\sum_{k=n}^{2n}x_{k}\right|=\sum_{k=n}^{2n}x_{k}\geq\sum_{k=n}^{2n}x_{2n}\geq nx_{2n}=(1/2)(2n)x_{2n}.
\end{align*}
Similarly, $(2n+1)x_{2n+1}$ is arbitrarily small.

Comment: Vandalistic downvote?  Adding compensatory upvote.