# Proving $na_n \to 0$, if $\sum a_n$ is convergent such that the terms are non-negative decreasing sequence using condensation test.

Tags: sequences-and-series

[If $(a_n)\subset[0,\infty)$ is non-increasing and $\sum a_n<\infty$, then $\lim{n a_n} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/if-a-n-subset0-infty-is-non-increasing-and-sum-a-n-infty-then-lim)

In this question, they have proved that there exists a subsequence $ka_k \to 0$. But we should prove the sequence is Cauchy right? Is Cauchy condensation test really helpful? How to proceed further?

Comment: Proving a sequence is Cauchy only proves it converges, but not what it converges to. The condensation test is about sums, and I suspect it is not helpful. What happens if the sequence $ka_k$ does not converge to zero? Its elements will always be greater than some non-zero $x$. Then you can perhaps compare $a_n$ to $x/n$ and prove by contradiction.

Comment: The sequence converges to where the subsequence converges.

Comment: If a sequence is convergent than it and every subsequence converge to the same value. That is not the Cauchy condensation test. We know that $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ is not convergent. What do you get if you do the comparison I suggested?