# Given a series is convergent and its terms are non-increasing, the limit of its general term times n is zero

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that: if $a_1 \geq ... \geq … $ and $\sum a_n$ converges, then $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \cdot a_n = 0$

My initial idea was to say that since $\sum a_n$ converges, we know that $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$. I'm stuck trying to show that $a_n$ will decrease faster than $n$ increases as $n \rightarrow \infty$. The tools that can be used are sets, the real numbers, sequences of real numbers, and the initial concept of a convergent series. Further notions of series are yet to be defined.

Comment: You're probably going to need to give more context for this question.  E.g. what type of tools do you know?  There's a nice proof using Dominated Convergence, but there are certainly more elementary methods too.

Comment: Do you know root test?

Comment: The root test hasn't been defined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $(a_n)\subset[0,\infty)$ is non-increasing and $\sum a_n<\infty$, then $\lim{n a_n} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/if-a-n-subset0-infty-is-non-increasing-and-sum-a-n-infty-then-lim)

Comment: Let $L$ be the limit of $na_n$. Can you find a lower bound for the sum of $k$ consecutive terms of the series?

Comment: It does answer, thanks! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/if-a-n-subset0-infty-is-non-increasing-and-sum-a-n-infty-then-lim