# If $(a_n)$ is a decreasing real sequence and $\sum a_n$ converges, then does $\sum (-1)^n n a_n\ $ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, alternating-expression

**"Motivation"/Introduction:**

1. If $(a_n)$ is a decreasing real sequence and $\displaystyle\sum a_n $ converges, then $n a_n \to 0,\ $ for example, by the [Cauchy Condensation test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/71732/29156).
2. If $(a_n)$ is a real sequence and $\displaystyle\sum a_n $ converges but $(a_n)$ is not necessarily decreasing, then does $n a_n\to 0?$ No: for example, take:

$
a_n:=
\begin{cases}
 2^{-n}&\text{if}\, n\neq 2^k\\
\frac{1}{k^2}&\text{if}\, n = 2^k\\
\end{cases}
$

Therefore, if  $(a_n)$ is a real sequence and $\displaystyle\sum a_n $ converges but $(a_n)$ is not necessarily decreasing, then $\displaystyle\sum n a_n\ $ and $\displaystyle\sum (-1)^n n a_n\ $ do not necessarily converge, by the counter-example above.

$$$$

This leads to the following question, for which I do not have an answer:

> If $(a_n)$ is a decreasing real sequence and $\displaystyle\sum a_n $
> converges, then does $\displaystyle\sum (-1)^n n a_n\ $ converge?

I was thinking we could apply [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) or [Cauchy's Condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) somehow, but I don't quite see how.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, $\sum (-1)^n n a_n$ is convergent under the given conditions.

Since $na_n \to 0$ it suffices to show that the partial sums with even index are convergent:

$$
 S_{2N} = \sum_{n=1}^{2N} (-1)^n n a_n = \sum^{2N}_{\substack{n =2\\ n \text{ even}}} \left( -(n-1)a_{n-1} + n a_n\right) \\
= \sum^{2N}_{\substack{n =2\\ n \text{ even}}} a_{n-1}
- \sum^{2N}_{\substack{n =2\\ n \text{ even}}} n(a_{n-1}-a_n)
=: A_{2N} - B_{2N} \, .
$$

On the right we have two sums with non-negative terms, we will show that both sums are bounded above and therefore convergent.

The first one is easy:
$$
 A_{2N} = \sum^{2N}_{\substack{n =2\\ n \text{ even}}} a_{n-1} \le 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n  \, .
$$
The second sum can be estimated by adding the terms for odd $n$:
$$
 B_{2N} \le \sum_{n=2}^{2N}  n(a_{n-1}-a_n)
= \sum_{n=2}^{2N} \bigl((n-1)a_{n-1} - na_n \bigr) + \sum_{n=2}^{2N} a_{n-1}
$$
There is a telescoping sum on the right, so we get
$$
B_{2N} \le a_1 - 2Na_{2N} + \sum_{n=2}^{2N} a_{n-1} 
\le a_1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n 
$$
and that finishes the proof.

---

*Remark:* Using the above estimates we can also obtain lower and upper bounds for the value of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n n a_n$ in terms of the given series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$. Let
$$
 S_{\text{odd}} = \sum^{\infty}_{\substack{n =1\\ n \text{ odd}}} a_n \, , \, 
 S_{\text{even}} = \sum^{\infty}_{\substack{n =2\\ n \text{ even}}} a_n \, .
$$
Then $A_{2N} \to S_{\text{odd}}$ and $0 \le B_{2N} \le a_1 +S_{\text{odd}} + S_{\text{even}}$, so that
$$
 \boxed{-a_1 - S_{\text{even}} \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n n a_n \le S_{\text{odd}} \, .}
$$
Both bounds are sharp, as can be seen by considering sequences of the form
$$
 a_1, a_1, a_3, a_3, a_5, a_5, \cdots
$$
and
$$
 a_1, a_2, a_2, a_4, a_4, a_6, a_6 \cdots \, .
$$